# Fetching orders details throught flipkart api using PHP(how to recall function without rewrite function declaration)

Tags: php, function, api, flipkart-api

I am fetching order details through Flipkar order Api.It is gives first 20(0-20) result at a time and for next records it gives next page url.
For fetching next 20 records(20-40) again we have to call curl with next page url and fetch orders .For this i am using code below:

```
$listingbulk=array();
$headers = array(
            'Cache-Control: no-cache',
            'Content-type: application/json',
            'Authorization: Bearer '.$fkt
            );
$bulkjson= '{
  "filter": {
       "orderDate": {
       "fromDate": "'.$orderfrom.'", 
       "toDate": "'.$orderto.'"
        }
    }
}';
$urlbulk  = "https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/v2/orders/search";
$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$urlbulk);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $bulkjson);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$resultbulksku = curl_exec($curl);
$listingbulk[] = json_decode($resultbulksku); 
if (curl_errno($curl)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($curl);
}
curl_close ($curl);
$nextPageUrl= $listingbulk[0]->nextPageUrl;
if ($nextPageUrl !=''){
    $newpageurl=   orderFk($nextPageUrl,$headers);
    if ($newpageurl !='') {
        $newpageurl2=   orderFk($newpageurl,$headers);
        if ($newpageurl2 !=''){
            $newpageurl3=   orderFk($newpageurl2,$headers);
        }
    }
}
```

Function is here :

```
function orderFk($nextPageUrl,$headers){
    $fp = fopen('order/order'.$currenttime.'.csv',"a");
    $urlbulk1  = "https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/v2/".$nextPageUrl;
    $curl1 = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_URL,$urlbulk1);
    curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $resultbulksku1 = curl_exec($curl1);
    $listingbulk1[] = json_decode($resultbulksku1); 
    if (curl_errno($curl1)) {
          echo 'Error:' . curl_error($curl1);
    }
    curl_close ($curl1);
    $listingbulk=$listingbulk1;
    $newnextPageUrl= $listingbulk1[0]->nextPageUrl;
    return $listingbulk;    
}
```

I want to crate if else condition dynamically so if "next pageurl" is exist in response it should  call again the same function with new url  ( without calling  function multiple times in if else condition).
If anyone has solution for this please reply.(answer with working example would be more helpful)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something like this, inside order function use while loop, exit on error or loop exceed the maxpage. In $list u have all responses.

```
function orderFk($nextPageUrl,$headers){
    $page = 1;
    $maxpage = 100;
    $exit = 0;
    $list = array();
    while(strlen($nextPageUrl)){
       $urlbulk  = "https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/v2/".$nextPageUrl;
       $curl = curl_init(); 
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$urlbulk);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
       $resultbulk = curl_exec($curl);
       $nextPageUrl = '';
       if(curl_errno($curl)) {
          $exit = 1;
       }
       curl_close($curl); // close before exit while loop
       if($exit==1 || $page>$maxpage){
          break;
       }
       $listingbulk = json_decode($resultbulk);
       if(strlen($listingbulk[0]->nextPageUrl)>0){
          $nextPageUrl = $listingbulk[0]->nextPageUrl;   
       }
       $list[] = $listingbulk;
       $page++;
    } 
    return $list;
  }
```

Comment: page url is string like:   [nextPageUrl] => /orders/search/ewogICJzb3J0IiA6IHsKICAgICJmaWVsZCIgOiAicGlja3VwX2RhdGUiLAogICAgIm9yZGVyIiA6ICJhc2MiCiAgfSwKICAiZmlsdGVyIiA6IHsKICAgICJzZWxsZXJfaWQiIDogImExY2E4MWNmMTllZjQ0NzAiLAog

Comment: in this case, function will look as yours orderFk($nextPageUrl,$headers) but in loop, on top, create new constant $currentPageUrl = $nextPageUrl, after curl_exec set this constant as null, after curl_error create IF statement where u will checking if $listingbulk[0]->nextPageUrl exists, if exists then update $currentPageUrl = $listingbulk[0]->nextPageUrl;
I WILL EDIT ME ANSEWR